# Emacs - nxml-mode causes memory overflow

Tags: memory, emacs, nxml

It seems, that nxhtml-mode is the only really interesting solution to editing mixed html-files in emacs (with snippets of php, css etc.); that is why I once more try to get an answer via stackoverflow, knowing that the information I can provide is rather poor.

Using nxhtml-mode or nxml without nxhtml (which is to my knowlede the base for nxhtml) I get serious memory problems in emacs. Working within an xhtml file for while with nxml-mode on, emacs seems to try to validate, stops after a while a tells me in the mode-line "MEM FULL". There is no other option to kill the emacs process. It is difficult to reproduce this behaviour consistantly but it happens seemingly in the following cases:

- Set a mark, use C-M-n to jump to the closing tag to mark a region
- Jumping around in the file tag-wise (using C-M-n and C-M-p)

I get the impression that emacs is overwhelmed trying to validate the file. I already split up my dot-emacs and set up a very reduced configuration just for testing nxml-mode and to make sure, that the mode is not interfering with some other extension. It seems this mode causes the problems, because I still get the described behaviour.

I am using emacs 23.2.1 on Linux Mint 11. The last time I tried nxhtml it was version 2.08. I posted a similar question [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247666/emacs-nxhtml-mode-memory-full).

Answer (score 0):

latest nXhtml is here:

https://launchpad.net/nxhtml

maybe file a bug report, if it still exists